Exception thrown in async React method is not caught in global error handler
I use React and have a code as this:
export default App;
window.onerror = function(error) {alert("Error caught: " + error);};
function App() {    
    perform().catch((error) =>{
        console.error('Error: '+error);
        throw error;
    });
}
async function perform() {
    throw Error("here");
}


But window.onerror is never invoked. Any ideas why?

perform().catch((error) =>{
  console.error('Error: '+error);
  throw error;
});

This throw is happening in the callback of a promise, so it causes  the promise to reject. window.onerror doesn't get called for unhandled promise rejections. For that, you can do:
window.onunhandledrejection = function (event) {
  alert("Error caught: " + event.reason);
}

